# How does Google bill for compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am currently running the free trial with 300$ credit.
There's one instance present in the console. Does Google bill for 'running' the instance or 'connecting' it to SSH?

Comment: for running instance

Comment: Is it good practice to start and stop the instance or should I keep it running?
I am using it to build and compile Android ROMs, there won't be any background process running otherwise.

Comment: you can start/stop instance any time, there're no problem with it

Answer (score 0):

Google charges compute instances by the time they're running (started) according to CPU and RAM, there are additional charges for disks and network. There are discounts for long running instances and for commitments. pricing information is available at https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing

You can start and stop instances any time and it depends on your workload... for your use-case of compiling things you may use preemptible instances which are much cheaper - https://cloud.google.com/preemptible-vms/